# Testing spheres without extracting planes

Tags: opengl, glm, frustum, frustum-culling

I am currently a bit stuck. On OpenGL I am attempting to do view frustum culling,
so far I managed to do it by using a PCM.
Where center is the world position of the mesh.

```
bool shouldRenderMesh(mat4 VP, vec3 center, float radius)
{
    vec4 transformedCentre = VP * vec4(center, 1);
    vec3 PCN = vec3(
        transformedCentre.x / transformedCentre.z,
        transformedCentre.y / transformedCentre.z,
        transformedCentre.z / transformedCentre.z
        );
    if( abs(PCN.x) > 1 || abs(PCN.y) > 1 || abs(PCN.y) > 1 )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
```

The problem is, while the approach works, items will disappear too soon, as the testing is based on the centre point of the mesh, rather than the bounding box.

Is it possible to test a sphere or box without extracting planes?

Thanks